# React Beautiful DnD unable to drop items to the bottom of a list or outside viewport

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a simple react dnd list that I need to drop items into from another list. When there are too many items in the list and the vertical scroll bar is present, it is not allowing me to add.  I would need to scroll up to the top and drop the item near the beginning of the list.  Is there a way to fix this?

I found a github issue for this as well: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1903

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982182/react-beautiful-dnd-drag-out-of-position-problem? I experienced that 'transform' problem as well.

Comment: not exactly since the problem occurs when I'm dragging between 2 different containers.  I'll check anyway if the fix can work for my issue.  Thank you!

Comment: also, the link to the github issue gives a 404 error

Comment: were you able to achieve this?